# Problem while compiling a solidity contract with truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, ether, windows

Each time that I compile a contract with truffle I get this error: (cmd)

```
# Compiling your contracts...
> Compiling .\contracts\HW.sol Error executing vyper: 'vyper' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Truffle v5.1.58 (core: 5.1.58) Node v14.15.1
```

Any Idea on how to fix it? I tried installing vyper v1.0.0 but nothing changed

Comment: I tried installing pip on windows and then I tried 
`pip install vyper`
so I installed vyper but the issue stays

Comment: Have you tried this tuto : https://medium.com/quiknode/build-smart-contracts-in-vyper-with-truffle-5-82aa0a60b3e7 ?

Comment: @clement nah I have changed OS ,I'm on linux now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very similar error appeared on my Ubuntu Vagrant VM after uninstalling and reinstalling truffle and then trying to run my truffle tests.

```
Error executing vyper
/bin/sh: vyper: command not found
```

My fix was:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip install vyper
```

I then had to edit my path in ~/.profile so truffle could find vyper:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/.local/bin
```

After that the error was gone.